# troubleshooting reverse string

Tags: assembly, x86, masm, irvine32

I write a program to reverse a string it given, but it seems that the result didn't match.

I use foward and backward to indicate the index to exchange and finally add the null 
character in the tail.

The result should be

```
67 6E 69 72 74 73 20 65 63 72 75 6F 73 20 65 68 74 20 73 69 20 73 69 68 54 00
```

but My result is

```
00 67 6E 69 72 74 73 20 65 63 72 75 6F 73 20 65 68 74 20 73 69 20 73 69 68 00
```

it seem something wrong, bur I cannot find out where is the bug.

Could you help me to find where might be wrong?

Thx in advance.

```
INCLUDE Irvine32.inc

.data
source BYTE "This is the source string",0;26
target BYTE SIZEOF source DUP('#')
strl BYTE 0 
foward DWORD 0
backward DWORD 0

.code
main PROC
    mov strl, LENGTHOF source;26
    dec strl; last char is 25. 26 is null
    movzx ecx, strl;count = 25 
    mov foward, 0
    movzx eax, strl
    mov backward, eax

    L1:
        mov esi, backward
        mov al,source[esi]
        dec backward

        mov esi, foward
        mov target[esi], al
        inc foward

        loop L1

    movzx esi, strl

    mov al,source[esi]
    mov target[esi], al



    mov esi,OFFSET target ; offset of variable
    mov ebx,1 ; byte format
    mov ecx,SIZEOF target ; counter
    call DumpMem

main ENDP

END main
```

Comment: Your result is just shifted for one position, it seems like very small bug, if you debug properly you should be able to catch it easily.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change this:

```
    mov esi, backward
    mov al,source[esi]
    dec backward
```

To:

```
    dec backward
    mov esi, backward
    mov al,source[esi]
```

because:

```
    movzx eax, strl
    mov backward, eax
```

initially `backward` points not to last element of string, but one after last (0 byte), so you first read it.

Comment: It success, Thank you. But why have to dec first? I thought that it is the last element because I have do that stringLength - 1?

Comment: @Liang-YuPan because it is not the last element of the string. If length if string is 3, then element indices are 0, 1, 2. Yeah, right `stringLength - 1`.